# How to add custom search field in magento from product attribute

Tags: magento, advanced-search

I wanted to add custom search option with following fields , search text,brand name (combo box) attribute and search button.On click of search button need to display search results.Need help on how to do this.

Comment: Have you actually tried anything yet?

Comment: Please post what you have tried so that others can help you.

Comment: I have not tried yet

Answer (score 1):

You can extend magento's default advance search which accessed under http://your-store.com/catalogsearch/advanced/

Secondly, if having time and interest, you can use elasticsearch for better and fast results + autosuggest with easy filtering.